Creating MediaController via buildAsync() never returns
I'm attempting to create a MediaController in Java as part of a Capacitor plugin. The RemoteStreamerService inherits MediaSessionService and implements the required methods and I can confirm it's running when this block runs. When I run the below code from my plugin, the listener is just never invoked. I see no errors in the logs and ListenableFuture just hangs around forever never resolving. Any idea what could be going wrong or even how to debug it?
    private ListenableFuture<MediaController> controllerFuture;
private void initPlayer() {
    SessionToken sessionToken =
            new SessionToken(getContext(), new ComponentName(getContext(), RemoteStreamerService.class));
    MediaController.Builder builder = new MediaController.Builder(getContext(), sessionToken);
    controllerFuture = builder.buildAsync();
    Log.d("stream", "Awaiting the future player");
    controllerFuture.addListener(() -> {
            Log.d("stream", "Got the player");
            try {
                player = controllerFuture.get();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(getContext()));
}


Is your MediaSessionService correct implemented? Take a look to https://developer.android.com/media/implement/playback-app#java - this Example works for me - good luck!

I followed that guide pretty closely and the can confirm the MediaSessionService is started. I'm even able to bind it to my activity and see the player and session. But the buildAsync() method still never returns.

I have tested your code, it works! maybe we can help if you post your manifest and your service code...
